# Foundational theories, their uses, interactions and comparisons?

Tags: logic, set-theory, category-theory, foundations, type-theory

Until now, I heard that there are some theories for building mathematical objects (or at least it is what it seems to my poor knowledge). Some of these are:

- Set theory;
- Logic;
- Category theory;
- Type Theory;
- Homotopy Type Theory;
- (Perhaps) Lambda calculus;
- Etc.

Until now I know that these seems to be different trials of foundations for mathematical objects, both with it's strong and weak points: I've heard - for example - that type theory allows the computional implementation of mathematical objects, while set theory makes it a little harder.

I've seen some books, for example Goldblatt's Topoi: *A categorical analysis of logic* - It seems that some of these theories, as in this case Logic and Category theory do interact somehow. I believe that there may be more interaction between them.

I'm looking for some resource about foundational theories, their uses, interactions and comparisons.

Comment: nLab seems like a good place to start. But they have a strong bias towards category theory, type theory and homotopy type theory. Don't be misguided, set theory is the way to go! ;-)

Comment: Don't be misguided, set theory is dying and cannot express what is really going on in mathematics (outside set-theory working groups) - category theory is the way to go. ;-)

Comment: \*Gets popcorn\*.

Comment: [I'm already with my theme song](http://youtu.be/btPJPFnesV4).

Comment: Can someone elaborate a little about what is different about set theory and category theory? I mean differences of what their are trying to achieve.

Comment: By all means any of these theories can be expressed in another one's language. The real point is their expressiveness. The minimalism of Set Theory contrasts with the profusion of different concepts of Categories etc. But sets are represented in Category Theory as members of a specific category, while categories can perfectly be embedded in any set theory with proper classes.

Comment: @rewritten: Or with sets, if one considers the case of universes (or in $\sf ZFC$-talk, a proper class of inaccessible cardinals).

Comment: @Trismegistos That might be a different question that the OP's, because in most cases what set theorists are currently trying to achieve is not closely related to the role of set theory as a possible foundation for "ordinary" mathematics (I would guess that the analogous statement is true for many category theorists as well, but I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more like a long comment. The only two major approaches to the foundations that you list are *type theory* and *set theory.* Let me explain.

First, make note of a naming convention:

1. the axioms of group theory tell us what it looks like *inside* a group
2. the axioms of category theory us what it looks like *inside* a category

etc.

Following this convention, you might think that set theories tell us what it looks like "inside" a set. But they don't (life is *awfully* boring inside a mere set!). Rather, they tell us something about what the *universe* of sets looks like. A similar statement can be made in regards to type theory; type theories describe *universes* of types.

Another important observation is the following. Using [insert your favourite set theory here], we can prove statements about the natural numbers. For example, $\mathrm{ZFC}$ proves that a variety of other formal systems are consistent; or in other words, that there does not exist a natural number $n$ such that so-and-so formal system proves a contradiction in $n$ or fewer steps. Type theories like [Martin Lof type theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory) also have this ability.

On the other hand, neither the group theory axioms nor the category theory axioms tell us very much about the natural numbers. They just have no "foundational power." So I guess I would say that category theory is "ubiquitous" without really being "foundational." Don't be misguided; set theory and category theory solve very different problems. Set theories (and type theories) attempt to discern truth from falsehood, whereas category theory is a *conceptual* tool; the point is to conceptualize mathematics in a unified way. There's essentially no conflict between the two.

For these reasons and others, the only two major approaches to the foundations that you list are *type theory* and *set theory.* (That's not an exhaustive list; another example would be Lawvere's axiomatization of the "category of all categories.") I hope this comment has clarified a few things.

Comment: Maybe you should also mention Mereology as an alternative to conceptualize mathematics in a unified way. See [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjKjbfCgJHQAhVDsI8KHRc0AXMQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tc.umn.edu%2F~hellm001%2FPublications%2FMereologyandPhilMath.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGbchqW4CfSDfoTXVMsqilDI-BLmw).

Comment: @user170039, I don't know anything about mereology. Perhaps you can write something?